# On Script included Event

Tags: javascript

There is possible to listen on script including ?

Something like this :

```
document.querySelector('script').addEventListener('beforeinclude', function(e){
  //Function executed before each tag like <script src="path/to/jquery.min.js"> be included
})
```

I've seen something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/beforescriptexecute_event) but haven't seen more informations about it.

Comment: its not clear what you need to do

Comment: What I want is to know if there is possibility to execute a function before inclusion of each script included by script tag

Comment: The script element [exposes no events to the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement)

Comment: I know ! I just want to know if it's possible to do something like this.

Comment: No. It's not possible.